# function to compare three values

Tags: c, compare

Let say if I declare three variable (int) a,b,c.
And want to know if the value of any two of three of those is equal or not.
Is there any kind of function in C to help me through this?
Or should I make use of simply if else statement?

Comment: `bool anyeq = a == b ? true : b == c ? true : a == c`.

Answer (score 4):

Your could check:

```
int two_are_equal;
two_are_equal = a == b || b == c || a == c;
```